# EventLogInstaller Full Setup with Categories?

Tags: event-log

It appears the MSDN docs are broken concerning creating an Event Log completely along with a definitions file for messages. I am also lost on how to setup Categories (I have custom numbers in the 3000's for messages).

Can anyone point me to a link or show sample code on how to make this right?

Answer (score 0):

You should start (if you haven't done so already) here:

[EventLogInstaller Class (System.Diagnostics)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventloginstaller.aspx)

The sample provided there is the foundation for what you want to do. To sum it up, build a public class inheriting from `System.Configuration.Install.Installer` in an assembly (could be the same DLL where you have the rest of your application, a separate DLL, or an EXE file), decorate it with the `RunInstaller` attribute, and add your setup code in the constructor:

```cs
using System;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;

[RunInstaller(true)]
public class MyEventLogInstaller: Installer
{
    private EventLogInstaller myEventLogInstaller;

    public MyEventLogInstaller() 
    {
        // Create an instance of an EventLogInstaller.
        myEventLogInstaller = new EventLogInstaller();

        // Set the source name of the event log.
        myEventLogInstaller.Source = "NewLogSource";

        // Set the event log that the source writes entries to.
        myEventLogInstaller.Log = "MyNewLog";

        // Add myEventLogInstaller to the Installer collection.
        Installers.Add(myEventLogInstaller);   
    }
}
```

When you have your assembly compiled, you may use the `InstallUtil` tool available through the Visual Studio Command Prompt to run the installer code.

Regarding the message definition file (which includes category definitions), the MSDN documentation for `EventLogInstaller.MessageResourceFile` mentions that you should create an .mc file, compile it, and add it as a resource to your assembly. Digging around, I found an excellent post which should guide you to the end, here:

[C# with .NET - Event Logging](https://web.archive.org/web/20130303025352/http://roque-patrick.com/windows/final/bbl0134.html) *(Wayback Machine)*